# match a string with regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have issues with matching a string with regexp in JS.
I can use this:

```
/"[^"]*?"/g
```

in this string:

```
" this is a string "
```

but I can not use that in this:

```
" this is a \"string\" "
```

how can i fix that?
thanks.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you told us what it's supposed to match specifically ?

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. What exactly do you mean by "use this ... in this string"? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Are the quotes in your question literally part of the string? i.e., when you write `" this is a string "`, are you expressing an 18-character or 20-character string? Are you using literal notation (where `/` starts an escape sequence) or the actual character-for-character values present in the string (where a `/` is just a `/` character)?

Comment: I want match strings in a string. I mean I want to match those strings with a regular expression. I want to find anything between " and " but not \" .

Comment: Do you want to match empty string also like `""` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correct, what you want to do is test is a string is in correct format? so no premature string endings?

If that is the case you could use `/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"/g`

Comment: This is probably closer to what he needs, but I don't think he realizes that. A faster way is `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`

Comment: @sln So why use such complicated regex when `"(.*)"` can does the same?

Comment: @Kasra - Its not complicated, its the standard unrolled-loop method. Its 3-5 times faster than the alternation method.

Comment: thanks. and finally this is working even better: `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'`

Comment: Now test this solution with `\"a\" "b"`

Comment: @anubhava that is not necessary. nobody can't use such a thing in CSS or JavaScript codes directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^\\]?(".*?[^\\]")
```

You can try something like this.You will need to grab the group or capture and not match.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/30

or

```
(?:[^\\]|^)(".*?[^\\]")
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/31

Comment: @moisrex did this fail in nay case?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you shouldn't use `[^"]*` also you don't need none-greedy you can use following regex for matching all between 2 quote :

```
/"(.*)"/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF6bY8/1)

And if you want to match anything between `"` you can simply use a word character matcher with white-space matcher within a character class with  a global modifier :

```
/[\w\s]+/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK9cA8/2)

As another way you can use a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
/(?<!\\)"(.*?)(?<!\\)"/
```

Comment: @moisrex Its negative look behind and will match string that not preced by pattern after `?<!` read more http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: unfortunately look-behind does not supports in JavaScript. but thanks for mentioning that. I learned a lot today.

Comment: Using `(?<!\\)"` prevents quotes preceded by a backslash, but it does in this situation too: `\\"` where the quote is preceded by two (or an even number) of backslashes. In these cases the quote is no more escaped.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte So in this case that you are talking about it can has a lot of scenarios. It's just a recipe for this case!